How to cite a single-page item with amsrefs?
I am quoting a 2-sentence passage out of a (long) book and I want my bibliographic entry to include the number of the page where I found that passage. The passage is in an essay within a collection, so I'm using the book option of the article entry type. Sadly, amsrefs doesn't have a page option, and when I use pages, the output I get from XeLaTeX has the abbreviation "pp." whereas, obviously, the correct abbreviation is "p."
Here's an MWE:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[initials]{amsrefs}
\begin{document}
\noindent
I think you'll agree that this is a highly relevant quote:
\begin{quote}
  Ce qui est simple est tourjours faux.
  Ce qui ne l'est pas est inutilisable.

  ---Paul Val\'ery~\cite{Valéry:mpa:1960}
\end{quote}
Wasn't that a highly relevant quote?

\begin{bibdiv}
  \begin{biblist}
    \bib{Valéry:mpa:1960}{article}{
      author = {Valéry, Paul},
      title = {Mauvaises Pens\'ees et Autres},
      book={
        title = {\OE{}uvres II},
        publisher = {\'Editions Gallimard},
        date = {1960},
      },  
      pages = {864}
    }   
  \end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}
\end{document}

Though I don't see anything about this in User’s Guide to the amsrefs Package at ams.org, I gotta think there's a way to handle this kind of situation. But how?
Now I've found the \DashPages command, but I've not figured out yet exactly how to use it. Does it involve tweaking the existing \BibSpec entries?
